# Redirect to new page/UI/display in kivy app

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have below example kivy app i want to redirect to new page/display after the popup box based on some validation. How to redirect to new UI/page after popup ends?

example.kv

```
AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'center'
    Button:
        height: 40
        width: 100
        size_hint: (None, None)
        text: 'Click Me'
        on_press: app.process_button_click()

<PopupBox>:
    pop_up_text: _pop_up_text
    size_hint: .5, .5
    auto_dismiss: True
    title: 'Status'   

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: _pop_up_text
            text: ''
```

And main.py as

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

import time, threading

class PopupBox(Popup):
    pop_up_text = ObjectProperty()
    def update_pop_up_text(self, p_message):
        self.pop_up_text.text = p_message

class ExampleApp(App):
    def show_popup(self):
        self.pop_up = Factory.PopupBox()
        self.pop_up.update_pop_up_text('Running some task...')
        self.pop_up.open()

    def process_button_click(self):
        # Open the pop up
        self.show_popup()

        # Call some method that may take a while to run.
        # I'm using a thread to simulate this
        mythread = threading.Thread(target=self.something_that_takes_5_seconds_to_run)
        mythread.start()

    def something_that_takes_5_seconds_to_run(self):
        thistime = time.time() 
        while thistime + 5 > time.time(): # 5 seconds
            time.sleep(1)

        # Once the long running task is done, close the pop up.
        self.pop_up.dismiss()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a ScreenManager widget.